# How to make email sent using php's mail() reflect in "sent items" of sender's mailbox

Tags: php, email

Let's assume my php script sends a mail to **receiver@example.com** using the function `mail()`. In the `$headers` parameter of `mail()`, I specified **sender@example.net**. If receiver@example.com replies to this email, he may or may not include the whole conversation while replying. This will make impossible to know, for what the receiver is replying.

If there is a way which sends the mail sent by mail() directly to the **"sent items"** box of the sender@example.net, It would greatly help.

I know an alternative way. That is to send sender@example.net a copy of mail sent to receiver@example.com whenever a mail is sent using `mail()` but that would reach the inbox which would again make it clumsy to track the conversation.

Please tell me if there is a way to reflect the sent mail in the **"sent items"** box of  **sender@example.net**.

Thank you

Peace to all...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not to simple...
PHP mail() just send an email throug system "sendmail" command, simplified it's just an smtp client.

What you need is an IMAP client - PHP has a good IMAPlib extension, let's go to try it. Btw, you need your user account to put the email to "sent items", may be it's not solvable.

Edited:

You should follow the instructions and examples on these sites:

http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mail-move.php
http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mail-copy.php

There are several example, I think you can do what you want with help of those.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... Please come back to answer my question if you ever find a solution...

Answer (score 2):

You have to send a message via SMTP. PHP's mail() function doesn't provide this functionality, but you can write your own or use some existing solution. For example, [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.sending.html) from Zend framework, or PEAR's [Net_SMTP](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_SMTP) package

Main idea is that you connect to SMTP of sender@example com and sends a message. And you'll get what you need.

Comment: Hmm... You can't put the sent email to user "sent items" box through SMTP - just through IMAP.

Comment: airween is right... I checked it. No mail was reflected in SENT MAIL box. Still, thanks for your reply...

Comment: You don't need to put it. It will be put automatically. Of course only in case when you're using the SMTP service which is related to the sender user. For example in Gmail it works like a sharm. Personally I'm using it on practice in this way.